# passing a string variable to boost::ASIO reader/handlers sause seg fault

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was trying to modify a boost::asio example when I hit this problem:
I simplified the code for easy reading(u'll see a lot of `cout`s for more help):

-Somewhere in my code, **I initiate an `async_read`:**

```
class WhoAreYouProtocol
{
public:
    std::string ID; //json string containing ID of the client
private:
    void WhoAreYou_handler(const boost::system::error_code& e,session_ptr sess) {

      ID.resize(1);//just for testing
      ID = "A";
      std::cout << "1.Address of String1 " << &ID << " value[" << ID << "] size " << ID.size() << std::endl; 
    sess->async_read(ID,
            boost::bind(&WhoAreYouProtocol::WhoAreYou_response_handler, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(ID), sess));
}

void WhoAreYou_response_handler(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::string &ID_, session_ptr sess) {//...  }
```

};

**Then, the program should do:**

1. first, ***read*** the size of the main buffer
2. ***resize*** a string variable to the size of incoming data
3. ***read*** the main buffer into the string variable

here is the code:
**Read**

```
class session
{
public:

  template <typename Handler>
  void async_read(std::string& t, Handler handler)
  {
      t.resize(2);//just testing
      std::cout << "Address of String2 " << &t << std::endl;
      std::cout << "String2 size " << t.size() << std::endl;
      t = "AB";
      std::cout << "2.Address of String " << &t << " value[" << t << "] size " << t.size() << std::endl;
    // Issue a read operation to read exactly the number of bytes in a header.
    void (session::*f)(const boost::system::error_code&,std::string&, boost::tuple<Handler>) = &session::handle_read_header<Handler>;
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(inbound_header_),boost::bind(f,this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(t),boost::make_tuple(handler)));


  }
```

**Resize and read the main buffer:**

```
  /// Handle a completed read of a message header. The handler is passed using
  /// a tuple since boost::bind seems to have trouble binding a function object
  /// created using boost::bind as a parameter.
  template <typename Handler>
  void handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code& e,std::string& t, boost::tuple<Handler> handler)
  {
      t.resize(3);//and again, just testing
      t = "ABC";
      std::istringstream is(std::string(inbound_header_, header_length));
      std::size_t inbound_data_size = 0;
      inbound_data_.resize(inbound_data_size);

      void (session::*f)(const boost::system::error_code&,std::string&, boost::tuple<Handler>) = &session::handle_read_data<Handler>;
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(inbound_data_),boost::bind(f, this,boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(t), handler));

  }
```

**and Finally the last problem handler :**

```
  /// Handle a completed read of message data.
  template <typename Handler>
  void handle_read_data(const boost::system::error_code& e,std::string& t, boost::tuple<Handler> handler)
  {
      std::cout << "4.Address of String " << &t  << std::endl;
      //any of the following lines crashes!!!!
      std::cout << "4. value[" << t << "] size " << t.size() << std::endl;
//    t.resize(4); //crash!!!
        std::string archive_data(&inbound_data_[0], inbound_data_.size());
        t = archive_data;//my target is to reach here but it crashes!!!!
  }

private:
  /// The size of a fixed length header.
  enum { header_length = 8 };

  /// Holds an outbound header.
  std::string outbound_header_;

  /// Holds the outbound data.
  std::string outbound_data_;

  /// Holds an inbound header.
  char inbound_header_[header_length];

  /// Holds the inbound data.
  std::vector<char> inbound_data_;
};
```

*In short, I passed a `string` in a few from the initial `async_read` down to the final handler(as you can see it took the few hops).*

**PROBLEM: In the last handler, almost every operation on the string crashed (cout, assign,resize)**

I will value your kind time to go over the code and let me know where I have done something wrong? ... and how to solve it :)

thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

`async_read` doesn't know what the buffer is, so it assumes it's a buffer it can just put data into, thereby overwriting the internal data of the string (and no it won't write to the buffer contained in the string which most likely is a pointer to memory allocated on the heap). This will lead to undefined behavior and the crash you're experiencing.

Use the buffering supplied by Boost ASIO, and then in the callback put that data into the string.

Comment: joachim pileborg, thanks, should I pass boost::buffer variable right from the start?

Comment: oh, but the first `async_read` is not `asio::async_read`. in the 2 `asio::async_read`s I used `char[]` and `vector<char>` . I passed `string` to my own `templated async_read` to send it over the hops to the final handler, and then fill it up using `vector<char>inbound_data_ `. `inbound_data_ `  actually gets data successfully(i just double checked). The problem is when I create a string out of this `inbound_data` and assign it to my original string, the program crash. Any other operation on the original string crashes too(in the last handler)